# Unable to connect to desktop server from android

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android

Yesterday I faced some strange issue while my laptop and Android device connected to same wifi network. I had a server running at port 80 on my laptop. When I tried accessing the website hosted on my laptop, I was unable to connect. According to the error message, there was no route to the destination host.

I was, however, able to access the site from another laptop.

Can somebody help me resolve this issue? Should I change the routing table of Android device?

Comment: Also this happened with other android phones as well

Comment: Did it work earlier? Is anything changed on the router? Can you ping the android device from your computers? You can use a PING app to check if you can reach both computers.

Comment: Yes it used to work earlier and I was not able to ping any of the computers however the computers were able to ping each other. Also it started working after sometime not sure how